# expression in cell only works 3/4 of the time

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the following expression in my background color property of my data cell for my matrix report.

If the value in the cell is a "0", then the cell color should be Red.  Other wise it is alternating between Blue and White.

I'd say it works on 75% of my cells. But sometimes, a cell with a "0" will be white or blue.

I can't find any rhyme or reason for it.

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!Total_Logged.Value)=0, "Red", iif(RunningValue(Fields!UserName.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2, “Blue”, “White”))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Might there be a rounding issue? For instance, the sum isn't precisely 0 but 0.001

Comment: Is a value always being passed for Total_Logged, or might it be NULL in some cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help if `Total_Logged` has NULL values.

```
=IIF(IIF(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Total_Logged.Value)), 0 , 
    Sum(Fields!Total_Logged.Value)) = 0, 
    "Red", IIF(RunningValue(Fields!UserName.Value,CountDistinct,Nothing) Mod 2,
    “Blue”, “White”))
```